# What is the value of $e^2$ in CGS units?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, units, si-units

Seems yo me that units of the square power of electron charge $e^2$ are in the  SI units system Coulombs squared, $[C^2]$.

But what are the corresponding units of $e^2$ in CGS units system? I am not sure if similarly, the "$[statC^2]$" applies here because the base units for CGS statC charge units are much more complicated,

$$
1 \mathrm{statC}=1 \mathrm{dyn}^{1 / 2} \cdot \mathrm{cm}=1 \mathrm{~cm}^{3 / 2} \cdot \mathrm{g}^{1 / 2} \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1} \text {. }
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb#As_a_unit_of_charge

I am not so sure if that qualifies to be called as statC unit when raised to the power of 2?

So for example how you convert the electron charge $e^2$ from its value in $[C^2]$ SI units to CGS units system?

I am not so sure if $e^2 = 9 \cdot (1.602 \cdot 10^{-19})^{2} \cdot 10^{18}$
$[statC^2]$, is the correct conversion in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The normal rules of units still work in cgs units. So we have $$e=4.8032 \ 10^{-10} \mathrm{\ cm^{3/2} \ g^{1/2} \ s^{-1}}=4.8032 \ 10^{-10} \mathrm{\ statC}$$ Then it is straight standard algebra to get $$e^2=2.307 \ 10^{-19} \mathrm{\ cm^{3} \ g^{1} \ s^{-2}}=2.307 \ 10^{-19} \mathrm{\ statC^2}$$

The normal rules of unit algebra still apply. What is different are the formulas of physics. For instance Maxwell’s equations have different constants.